# how to perform validations in asp.net mvc?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

In my model layer, I have written the code like this for password :

```
[Required]
[StringLength (100,ErrorMessage 
               ="The {0} must be atleast {2} characters long.",MinimumLength=6)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name="Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

But it is not getting affected in my register page.

Comment: Need to see some Controller Action code we think

Comment: What validation doesn't take effect? Can you please fully describe your scenario?

Comment: For login validations, please refer this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/249452/ASP-NET-MVC3-Validation-Basic There's a sample project showing how password validation is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regular expression e.g.:

For the regular expression:
public const string Password = @"^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$";

For the model:
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
[RegularExpression(RegularExpressions.Password, ErrorMessage = "At least 6 characters long, with upper and lower case and at least 1 number")]
[StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Password has a maximum length of 20 characters")]
public string Password { get; set; }

Also ensure that model state validation is performed as per this article:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx